# What physical evidence exists that shows motor proteins "walking" within a cell?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, proteins, biophysics

Various animations on the internet show the motor protein kinesin walking within a cell. Is this an approximation? How does this happen and (based upon what physical evidence) how do we know it "walks" like this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-uuk4Pr2i8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXyJG.jpg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMKlPDBRJ1E

Comment: Closely related from Sceptics-SE: [Is this what “happiness looks like”?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31119/is-this-what-happiness-looks-like).

Comment: It is known to be seen **in-vitro** (I've never yet seen practically). One technique includes using optical-tweezer (laser-trap); image example [here](http://www.cell.com/cms/attachment/520177/3536863/gr1.jpg) and [here](http://d1vn86fw4xmcz1.cloudfront.net/content/royptb/363/1500/2123/F4.large.jpg?width=800&height=600&carousel=1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you chose kinesins as an example class of motor proteins, I will also stick to them. In general, the movement mechanisms of kinesins are well studied and the general structure of kinesin proteins, that is a dimer, is known by [crystallography](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallography#Biology) (see [Kull et al. (1996)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v380/n6574/abs/380550a0.html) for the structure publication).

Even before that, the **movement of single kinesin molecules in discrete steps of approx. 8 nm** was shown by [Svoboda et al. (1993)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v365/n6448/abs/365721a0.html). To resolve single molecules, they used **optical trapping interferometry** (see [this](http://genomics.princeton.edu/shaevitzlab/OT_Practicle_Guide.pdf) practical guide to optical trapping by the Princeton University for more detailed information). Four years later, [Schnitzer and Block (1997)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v388/n6640/full/388386a0.html) were able to show that that for every step of approx. 8 nm lof a kinesin molecule, one ATP is hydrolysed. [Visscher et al. (1999)](http://www.nature.com.offsitelib.eva.mpg.de/nature/journal/v400/n6740/full/400184a0.html#B1) used **molecular force clamps** to study ATP and load dependent characteristics of single kinesin molecules.

So far, it appears to be that kinesins move by a 'hand-over-hand' mechanism: [Yildiz et al. (2004)](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/303/5658/676) **labelled single heads of kinesin dimer molecules with a fluorophore** and found that their data are congruent with a step of approx. 17 nm followed by a step of approx. 0 nm which indicates **that the two dimer hands alternate in movement**.

See also the review by [Hirokawa et al. (2009)](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v10/n10/full/nrm2774.html) for a general overview of kinesin movement.